# Display User's Infomation in MVC using @Model.xxxx

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, controller

I have a login page and registration page all are working fine. I have a users table i created in sql server database with the column Username, FullName, School, Course. I want to display all the user detail in a sidemenu view page in MVC. But when i login i get the error message"object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object". I also have a controller action. Please someone help.

This is for MVC

@model ORMOnlineExamApp.Models.Candidate

```
 <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="width:200px">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Candidate's Details</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>

                        <h4 style="font-weight:bold">Application No:</h4>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Model.Username
                    </p>

                    <hr />
                    <p>
                        <h4 style="font-weight:bold">Name:</h4>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Model.FullName
                    </p>
                    <hr />

                    <p>
                        <h4 style="font-weight:bold">School:</h4>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Model.School
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <p>
                        <h4 style="font-weight:bold">Course:</h4>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @Model.Course
                    </p>
                </div>





    //Controller
     public ActionResult Contact(string id)
            {
                using (ORMOnlineExamEntitiesApp db = new ORMOnlineExamEntitiesApp())
                {
                    var user = db.Candidates.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == id);
                    return View(user);
                }


            }


Please find the login page below:
 //Login POST
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(CandidateLogin login, string ReturnUrl = "")
        {
            string message = "";


            using (ORMOnlineExamEntitiesApp dc = new ORMOnlineExamEntitiesApp())
            {
                var v = dc.Candidates.Where(a => a.Username == login.Username).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {

                    if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(login.Password), v.Password) == 0)
                    {
                        int timeout = login.RememberMe ? 525600 : 20; // 525600 min = 1 year
                        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login.Username, login.RememberMe, timeout);
                        string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                        {
                            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Username, true);
                            Session["UserId"] = login.Username.ToString();
                            return RedirectToAction("Contact", "Home");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "Invalid credential provided";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Invalid credential provided";
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to interact with an object that is null. On what line are you getting this error?

Comment: Thank for your response. @Model.Username. Which is the identity they use in logging from the user's table. I was able to get the username using HttpContext. But the other details throws an error of object reference

Comment: Hmm in that case it means that Model is null. Given that, I suspect that this line is returning null: `var user = db.Candidates.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == id);` Try checking the id that is actually passed into the `(u => u.Username == id)` filter and see if your database has a Candidate with a matching username.

Comment: Please, help. I am new to MVC. I can easily achieve that in asp.net web form aspx using sqldatasource.

Comment: Hmm could you show me the code that redirects you to the Contact page after you login?

Comment: Kei, i have edited my initial code i posted. the section is the code you requested.

Comment: Ah okay, so the issue is here: `return RedirectToAction("Contact", "Home");` You aren't passing the id to the Contact action. Try changing this to `return RedirectToAction("Contact", "Home", new { id = login.Username.ToString() });`

Comment: As an alternative, since you have UserId stored in your session already, you can try this instead: `var user = db.Candidates.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == Session["UserId"] as string);` This would be preferred over passing the id into Contact, as anybody would be able to change the URL to read other users' contact information.

Comment: The first option is working, but the second is throwing up this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Ah okay, my apologies. In that case, split that statement into two steps. `var userId = Session["UserId"] as string;` `var user = db.Candidates.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == userId);`

Comment: Kei, you have really tried for me. Thanks. The second option is now throwing up an error of object reference set to null but the first option is working perfectly well.